# Find out how many pixels between the start of two elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="members" class="main">     
    <section class="top">
        <!-- Other Content -->
    </section>
    <section class="listing">
        <div class="holder container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="members-main col-sm-12">
                    <div class="members-head row">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Is there a way in `JavaScript` or `jQuery` that I can find out the amount of pixels between the *start* of the `#members` element and the *start* of the `.members-head` element?

Comment: If you want to get an ***exact*** number of pixels you have to conside the  zoom level used by the user. Look [here](http://blog.sebastian-martens.de/2009/12/how-to-detect-the-browser-zoom-level-change-browser-zoo/) for some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.members-head').offset().top - $('#members').offset().top
```

[Jquery offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

If you have multiple `.members-head` elements inside the `#members` one (as I suspect), you could try `$('.members-head:first')`, or loop through them with [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and do  `$(this).offset().top - $('#members').offset().top`

Comment: Wouldn't it be the other way around? `$('.members-head').offset().top - $('#members').offset().top` ?

Comment: yes, to be sure you could do abs(foo). I've changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Whilst zooming does affect the result of this, it doesn't matter a lot for me as it doesn't have to be 100% perfect.

Answer (score 2):

[**`offset().top`**](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) gives you the top position of elements.

```js
var distance = $('.members-head').offset().top - $('#members').offset().top;

alert("Distance is : " + distance)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="members" class="main">     
    <section class="top">
        Other Content 
    </section>
    <section class="listing">
        <div class="holder container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="members-main col-sm-12">
                    <div class="members-head row">
                        fdgfdgfdgdfgdfs
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. In IE (and I suspect in other browsers as well) I get a fraction (18.3999...), and worse, if I zoom in, I get the same results. That's not pixels, and definitely not accurate.

Comment: For IE, try [offsettop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)

Answer (score 1):

try this
you will get.

```
$('#members').offset().top - $('.members-head').offset().top
```